# Is the limit of this function equal to $1/2$ as $x \to \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $F$ be a proper closed set $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ and, for each $n=1,2,3,...$, let $F_{n} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \operatorname{dist}(x,F) \ge 1/n\}$. Define the sequence of functions:
$$f_{n}(x) = \frac{\operatorname{dist}(x,F_{n})}{\operatorname{dist}(x,F_{n})+\operatorname{dist}(x,F)}.$$

I know that each $f_{n}$ is continuous and $0 \le f_{n} \le 1$. However, how do I prove that $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f_{n}(x) = 1/2$?

Comment: Terminology correction: the limit doesn't go anywhere. The limit **is** $1$. A limit is a number.

Comment: Apart from that, are you sure the limit is not $1/2$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thanks, I corrected the title. The limit is $1/2$, of course. My mistake. I corrected it too.

Comment: It should be that $d(x, F_n)\uparrow d(x, F)$. If you prove this then you are done. It shouldn't be hard also because the left--hand side is clearly increasing, so you are reduced to prove that $\sup_n d(x, F_n)= d(x, F)$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro the limit is taken over $x$, not $n$ tho.

Comment: Oh, sorry, then my previous comment does not apply at all. Everything is now going to $\infty$ (paraphrasing your previous title).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro yes, $\operatorname{dist}(x,F_{n})$ and $\operatorname{dist}(x,F)$ both go to $\infty$. By the ration goes to a finite number?

Comment: Take $F= \{0\},$ ,then $dist(x,F) = |x|$ and $dist(x, F_n) = 0$ if $|x| \ge 1/n$, so for large $x$ we have $dist(x, F_n)=0,$ so your limit is zero right?